# Creating file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i am trying to do this

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\sample.text", filename);
```

where filename is a string type variable but i think through ASP.NET we can not create file.

can any one give me solution to create file on system

or even i am fail to to this also

```
Clipboard.SetText(filename);
```

it gives me STA exception

or another way i am thinking something like this

```
Response.Reditect("newpage.aspx", _blank, filename) // can this be possible?
```

a new page will open with containing text what ever in "filename"

Comment: Why do you think you can't use WriteAllText? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You can write to local files on the web server, but you will need permissions to do so, by default the website runs as a specific IIS user account, so, unless you have a directory you mark as writeable by that user, its not going to work.. Posting errors will help you get better responses.

Comment: i am able to create file with my pc because i am sever but other user will not be able because through scrpting language you cannot creat file other wise it lead to hacking !! or else the user will give permission to the other people to create file on his PC

Comment: @shruti - that is correct, are you wanting to create a file on the client? or just trying on the server but it's not working?

Comment: The most important question is what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to simply display the text to the user and saving the file is not a requirement? Or do you want to save the file on the client PC? In one example you are trying to write a file, in another you suggest to show the text in a browser, that would imply a file is not required? It would help if you could highlight what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See i just want to give the output to the user best way is to give them in a file or else give them in another page so that they can use the output with there concern.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 options as I see it, first ask the user to download the file:

```
FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\sample.text");
if (file.Exists)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    Response.End();
}
```

Or secondly as you suggest, output the content to the browser:
I would however not recommend the below, as it literally outputs the content of the file as text to the browser, note I did html encode it so that html isn't injected via the text file.

```
FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\sample.text");
if (file.Exists)
{
     Response.Clear();
     Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)));
     Response.End();
}
```